# "Adaptable" vs. "flexible"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

Are the words *adaptable* and *flexible* generally interchangeable? For example, do the following sentences have the same meaning?

> Older workers are less **adaptable** [...].
>
> Older workers are less **flexible** [...].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those two phrases have meanings which are broadly the same but not identical. *Adaptable* indicates long-term changes; *flexible* more short-term alterations. One might adapt to the introduction of a new shift pattern, and be flexible enough to work late next Tuesday.

But *adaptable* and *flexible* are generally not interchangeable: the former means "able to be adapted" (or possibly "able to adapt"), and the latter "able to flex or bend". To describe an adaptable building as flexible could conjure up an alarming image!

That said, a building might be adaptable enough to accommodate a warehouse or a school (a long-term use), or flexible enough to vary the number of rooms by having easily-moved internal walls (a shorter-term change).

Comment: Perhaps I could also have used "large-scale" and "small-scale" as alternative indicators of whether something is "adaptable" or "flexible" (respectively).

Answer (score 2):

From an engineering point of view, I wish to dispute Andrew's concept "Adaptable indicates long-term changes; flexible more short-term alterations" .

**Flexible is to provide inherent usability across a wide and changing spectrum of deployment situations, often without making significant or any changes to itself.**

The weapons are flexible to be deployed to either the Arctic, Iraq or Afghanistan. There is no modification necessary, except that, we have to make a slight permanent and long term modification to the trigger. And soldiers have to make a short term adjustment to the way they transport it.

**Adaptable is to be inherently modifiable to be deployed across diverse situations of deployment.**

The weapons are quickly adapted to being used in either the Arctic, Iraq or Afghanistan. The necessary modifications are quick but complex. They are not permanent changes to the weapon. Once a weapon has been adapted for the first time, soldiers would need to make a long term adjustment to the way they transport it.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to be more specific when clarity is necessary. In your scenario, *adaptable* is more specific to the person's willingness to change as *flexible* might be confused with the physical ability to bend.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *adaptable* and *flexible* are two valuable attributes of an effective teacher.

Here are two examples:

Teachers must be *flexible* to handle unexpected circumstances, such as sudden illness or emergencies.

Teachers *adapt* lesson plans to accommodate for the physical and intellectual needs of each student.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that an adaptable system has the capacity be deployed differently in different locations. A flexible system can react to different stimuli.

Answer (score 0):

### Easy - it's a matter of abstraction ...

> Older workers are not flexible [...]

is more specific than saying:

> Older workers are not adaptable [...]

Adaption happens by adding, removing, replacing or changing something.  There are only those 4 options, no more.

Being flexible is a specific ability to adapt though the means of flexing/changing.

What about adding, remove, replacing?

Well for things that adapt through change only i.e. by flexing, both adaptable and flexible 'mean' the same.

For things that adapt by removing something only, both adaptable and removable 'mean' the same.

For things that adapt by changing or removing something, adaptable is not that one-to-one!

**An example to further support the above**

"The plug didn't quite fit into the wall socket, so she jammed it in."

> The plug was 'flexible' enough to 'adapt' to the shape of the wall socket and all was good. (adapting by flexing/changing)

vs.

> The plug was not 'flexible' enough, a small peace broke off just enough to 'adapt' the shape of the plug to the shape of the wall socket and all was good. (adapting by breaking/removing)

**Extra notes**

In programming you'd consider 'adapting' to describe a state change visible to the outside (the WHAT) and 'flex' to describe the behavior that makes that change happen (the HOW).  As such 'adapt' would describe the contract of your interface and 'flex' would be the implementation of that interface.

Note: I am an older worker and I may adapt my thought model if evidence proves different :)